# Stratified random sampling with Google Earth Engine Error

Tags: classification, google-earth-engine

I am trying to sample points from a classified raster using Google Earth Engine, but am running into some problems. I developed a script based on the Classification video located [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/classification).

Here is a toy script that attempts to randomly sample a stratified raster.

```js
var ROI = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-82.562342, 35.589551,-82.562342, 35.589551); // define area

var features = [
    ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-82.56123, 35.59053,-82.55213, 35.59674),{class: 0}),
    ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-82.54245, 35.591453, -82.537172, 35.596496),{class:1})
];

var vect = ee.FeatureCollection(features);
print(vect);
Map.addLayer(vect);

var image = vect
  .filter(ee.Filter.neq('class', null))
  .reduceToImage({
    properties: ['class'],
    reducer: ee.Reducer.first()
});

Map.addLayer(image,{min:0,max:1,palette: ['black','white']});

var counts = {
  0:1000,
  1:1000,
};

print(counts)

var stratified = ee.Dictionary(counts)
    .map(function(klass,count) {
    klass = ee.Number.parse(klass)
    var masked = image.updateMask(image.eq(klass))
    return masked.addBands(ee.Image.pixelLonLat())
        .sample({
          region: ROI, 
          numPixels: 5000, 
          seed: klass})
        .randomColumn('x')
        .sort('x')
        .limit(ee.Number(count).min(100))
        .map(function(f) {
            var location = ee.Geometry.Point([f.get('longitude'),f.get('latitude')])
            return ee.Feature(location,f.toDictionary())
            })
    }).values()

stratified = ee.FeatureCollection(stratified).flatten(); 

print (stratified.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(),['Class']));
Map.addLayer(stratified);
print(stratified)
```

Unfortunately, I receive the error message: `The default WGS84 projection is invalid for aggregations. Specify a scale or crs & crs_transform.`

This error is mentioned on the projections [page](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/projections), but, doesn't offer any real solutions. Does anyone know how to aggregate using the aerial imagery in WGS84 on Google Earth Engine?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using just the stratifiedSample algorithm:  https://code.earthengine.google.com/e061f92736d8261f812db1dc2bfa8934

```js
var ROI = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-82.56277, 35.58935,-82.53436, 35.59996); // define area

var features = ee.FeatureCollection([
    ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-82.56123, 35.59053,-82.55213, 35.59674),{class: 0}),
    ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-82.54245, 35.591453, -82.537172, 35.596496),{class:1})
])

var classes = ee.Image().byte().paint(features, "class").rename("class")

Map.centerObject(ROI);
Map.addLayer(classes,{min:0,max:1,palette: ['grey','white']});

var stratified = classes.addBands(ee.Image.pixelLonLat())
    .stratifiedSample({
      numPoints: 1000,
      classBand: 'class',
      projection: 'EPSG:3665',
      scale: 10,
      region: features.geometry()
    }).map(function(f) {
      return f.setGeometry(ee.Geometry.Point([f.get('longitude'), f.get('latitude')]))
    })

print (stratified.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(),['class']));
Map.addLayer(stratified);
```

Comment: is the whole `setGeometry()` line doing the same as the argument `geometries: true` does? Seems would make the example simpler!

Comment: Yes. that's correct.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to edit the above script and get it to work by reprojecting the image, even though Google told me not to do it.

```js
var ROI = ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-82.56277, 35.58935,-82.53436, 35.59996); // define area

var features = [
    ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-82.56123, 35.59053,-82.55213, 35.59674),{class: 0}),
    ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Rectangle(-82.54245, 35.591453, -82.537172, 35.596496),{class:1})
];

var vect = ee.FeatureCollection(features);

var image_orig = vect
  .filter(ee.Filter.neq('class', null))
  .reduceToImage({
    properties: ['class'],
    reducer: ee.Reducer.first()
});

var image = image_orig.reproject('EPSG: 3665').clip(ROI); //reproject to UTM
print('Band names: ', image.bandNames()); // ee.List of band names
Map.centerObject(ROI);
Map.addLayer(image,{min:0,max:1,palette: ['grey','white']});

/*
var counts = image.reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram().unweighted())
    .get('first');
*/

var counts = {
  0:1000,
  1:1000,
};

print(counts)

var stratified = ee.Dictionary(counts)
    .map(function(klass,count) {
    klass = ee.Number.parse(klass)
    var masked = image.updateMask(image.eq(klass))
    return masked.addBands(ee.Image.pixelLonLat())
        .sample({
          region: ROI, 
          numPixels: 5000, 
          seed: klass})
        .randomColumn('x')
        .sort('x')
        .limit(ee.Number(count).min(100))
        .map(function(f) {
            var location = ee.Geometry.Point([f.get('longitude'),f.get('latitude')])
            return ee.Feature(location,f.toDictionary())
            })
    }).values()

stratified = ee.FeatureCollection(stratified).flatten(); 
print (stratified.reduceColumns(ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(),['first']));
Map.addLayer(stratified);
```

The creation of the counts object that is commented out is because GEE does not like the null key in the dictionary, and I don't know how to remove the null key in the dictionary.